# Nautilus shows progress unnecessarily after rename and remove

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 with the latest updates.
When i delete or rename a file (even a very small one) nautilus shows broken progress, that doesn't go out until 15 seconds or so, its not moving at all. When i rename 
a file it gives me the dialog "click cancel to cancel the renaming process" but its displayed after the rename and cancel just closes it.

I ve already tried to reinstall nautilus.
It doesn't haplen in Thunar, but i want to use nautilus since its heavily Integrated into Gnome.

Nautilus version is  1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4

Comment: It seems to be a problem with zeitgeist
I had to install it and run it and that helped, but i have to have a terminal open with zeitgeist running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, i reported it here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1783817